# How to fix a single character typo in a code sample?

Tags: discussion, spelling, code, code-block

I just wanted to fix a code sample which had a single character missing. However I can't do this because the minimum edit is 6 characters.

Can we make the checker smarter by allowing single character fixes for code blocks?

Comment: @MartijnPieters If that was an answer, I'd upvote it.

Comment: Colin, since you didn't specify the code sample was in an answer or a question, I want to point out that you should never edit code in a question.  That small typo might be the problem with the code that caused the poster to ask the question in the first place.

Comment: Sure, but this was in an answer provided by someone else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't. Leave a comment, or leave it to people with 2k+ rep to make the edit.

Suggested edits require review, and thus time from several people to review the change. To limit the size of the review queue only *suggested edits* have a minimal requirement of being non-trivial. High-rep users can make trivial edits at will as they can make the edit *directly* without having to go through the queue.